# Route params not available in guards

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-router-guards

Why isn't `id` available in the below guard?

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectDetailsGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

    canActivate() {
        const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

        console.log(id); // <-- undefined
    }

}
```

The same code works perfectly when implemented inside components.

Comment: Please look at https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate, canActivate is passed the route data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ActivatedRoute` can provide params only after the route is activated. If need to get `params` before it is activated i.e in `canActivate` method, try with `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`

```
canActivate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    const id = activatedRoute.params['id'];

    console.log(id); 
}
```